# output days of the week via function

Tags: php

help me please

I have a code

```
<?php
// date on Russian
function getDateRus(){
    $monthes = array(
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая', 6 => 'Июня', 7 => 'Июля', 8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
    );
    return ( (int)date('d') . ' ' . $monthes[(date('n'))] . date(' Y'));
}
// day on Russian
function getDayRus(){
    $days = array(
        'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда',
        'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'
    );
    return $days[(date('w'))];
}
echo "Today:" . getDateRus() . ", " . getDayRus();

?>
```

I need to put days off for a week ahead:

25 September, Monday

26 September, Tuesday

27 September, Wednesday

28 September, Thursday

29 September, Friday

30 September, Saturday

01 October, Sunday

I can print the dates for the week ahead, but without the Russian language.

how to deduce the dates for the week ahead and save the Russian language?

Comment: what is the output now? Or what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your structure slightly and I made use of the powerful function [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$monthes = array(
    1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
    5 => 'Мая', 6 => 'Июня', 7 => 'Июля', 8 => 'Августа',
    9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
);

$days = array(
    'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда',
    'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'
);

$dArray = array();
$date = new DateTime();
for($i=0; $i<7;$i++){
    $dArray[] = $date->format("d").' '.$monthes[$date->format("n")].','.$days[$date->format("w")];
    $date->modify("+1 day");
}

print_r($dArray);
```

Output:
`Array ( [0] => 25 Сентября,Понедельник [1] => 26 Сентября,Вторник [2] => 27 Сентября,Среда [3] => 28 Сентября,Четверг [4] => 29 Сентября,Пятница [5] => 30 Сентября,Суббота [6] => 01 Октября,Воскресенье )`

You can probs achieve this better by using [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). That way you will not need your day/month arrays